# Why Spring application is taking this much time to execute a simple code

Tags: java, spring

I am learning spring frame work  I did a basic hello world program in spring and I checked execution it is taking nearly 600 millisecond is spring frame work this much slow with this performance can we build a large application. here is the code

```
  public class MainApp {

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
      System.out.println(obj.getMessage());
      System.out.println("time in milliseconds"+System.currentTimeMillis()-
  time);
  }
  }
```

I am executing above code with spring configuration file for dependency injection. Why it is taking this much time for a simple code. here is the output

```
 Nov 22, 2017 10:17:15 PM 
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext 
prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing 
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@78e03bb5: 
startup date [Wed Nov 22 22:17:15 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 22, 2017 10:17:15 PM 
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader 
loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Hello World!
time in milliseconds 656
```

I am running above program in intel i3 processor with windows 8.1.

Comment: What do you have in Beans.xml? Spring framework has a lot to do to facilitate Dependency Injection and lots of other stuff, which it does at startup. hence the delay in start. It also depends on the number of beans you have defined in Beans.xml

Comment: Yes, the context is loaded on application startup and then never again.

Comment: 656 milliseconds is nothing. You should do something useful with your life besides throwing stones at a framework that has large market share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The testing approach is not entirely correct. In this execution everytime you start the framework + read beans definitions from xml. 656ms is pretty fast considering the volume of code it needs to load + read xml.

Once it started, it will work much faster.